# How to move a window up to the level of its parent window in i3wm?

Tags: window-management, i3

Suppose I have window w1, w2 open, and sub-window w1-a, w1-b with w1 as their parent window. Is there a way to move w1-a up to its parent window level?

Comment: I'm starting to think containers are almost a un-feature. When you have 10 virtual desktops and windows spontaneously zap themselves to the appropriate work space, is it really necessary to have windows placed into a tree structure?

Answer (score 27):

I found the answer by watch the video tutorial on i3 website:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>$mod</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

Focus parent:

<kbd>$mod</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

I hope this might be useful for other people who is also new to the i3wm.

Comment: Downvote - answer describes a specific i3 configuration but doesn't include the configuration text.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to expand on the author's answer.
`Shift+$mod+Up` (`move up` for `w1-a`) is very dependent what your current layout is.

Let's say the initial state of the container tree is:

```
.
├── w1
│   ├── w1-a
│   └── w1-b
└── w2
```

(Note here that w1 is not directly visible - only its two children containers / windows are.)

However while this specifies an ordering of the children of any given parent, it doesn't specify whether each container uses a horizontal or vertical split, and that will affect the outcome of the `move up` operation.

#### Reordering within the same level in the container tree

For example if you use it with `w1-b` physically below `w1-a` in a vertical split:

```
. (horizontal split)
├── w1 (vertical split)
│   ├── w1-a
│   └── w1-b
└── w2
```

then it will just switch them around moving `w1-b` above `w1-a` and *not* to the parent top-level.
The container tree now looks like this:

```
. (horizontal split)
├── w1 (vertical split)
│   └── w1-b
│   ├── w1-a
└── w2
```

Visually, the change will look like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+      +------------------------------------------+
| +-----------------+  +-----------------+ |      | +-----------------+  +-----------------+ |
| | w1              |  | w2              | |      | | w1              |  | w2              | |
| | +-------------+ |  |                 | |      | | +-------------+ |  |                 | |
| | | w1-a        | |  |                 | |      | | | w1-b        | |  |                 | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | |             | |  |                 | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | |             | |  |                 | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | |             | |  |                 | |
| | +-------------+ |  |                 | |      | | +-------------+ |  |                 | |
| | +-------------+ |  |                 | | ---> | | +-------------+ |  |                 | |
| | | w1-b        | |  |                 | |      | | | w1-a        | |  |                 | |
| | | (move up)   | |  |                 | |      | | |             | |  |                 | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | |             | |  |                 | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | |             | |  |                 | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | |             | |  |                 | |
| | +-------------+ |  |                 | |      | | +-------------+ |  |                 | |
| +-----------------+  +-----------------+ |      | +-----------------+  +-----------------+ |
+------------------------------------------+      +------------------------------------------+
```

#### Moving one level higher (probably what the questioner intended)

If on the other hand `w1-a` is to the left of `w1-b` and `w2` above `w1`:

```
. (vertical split)
├── w1 (horizontal split)
│   ├── w1-a
│   └── w1-b
└── w2
```

then after executing `move up` on `w1-b`, you will end up with `w2` and `w1-b` on the same (top) level of the tree, but `w1-a` will still be in `w1`  which can be quite confusing, especially given that `w1` itself is just an invisible container.

The container tree will now look like this:

```
.
├── w1-b
├── w1
│   └── w1-a
└── w2

+------------------------------------------+      +------------------------------------------+
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | w1                                   | |      | | w1-b                                 | |
| | +---------------+  +---------------+ | |      | |                                      | |
| | | w1-a          |  | w1-b          | | |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | |               |  | (move up)     | | |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | |               |  |               | | |      | | w1                                   | |
| | |               |  |               | | |      | | +----------------------------------+ | |
| | +---------------+  +---------------+ | |      | | | w1-a                             | | |
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | | |                                  | | |
| +--------------------------------------+ | ---> | | +----------------------------------+ | |
| | w2                                   | |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| |                                      | |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| |                                      | |      | | w2                                   | |
| |                                      | |      | |                                      | |
| |                                      | |      | |                                      | |
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
+------------------------------------------+      +------------------------------------------+
```

If you were then to try to move `w1-a` up, no visual change would be apparent, but the tree would change and `w1` no longer exists:

```
.
├── w1-b
├── w1-a
└── w2

+------------------------------------------+      +------------------------------------------+
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | w1-b                                 | |      | | w1-b                                 | |
| |                                      | |      | |                                      | |
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | w1                                   | |      | | w1-a                                 | |
| | +----------------------------------+ | |      | |                                      | |
| | | w1-a                             | | |      | |                                      | |
| | |                                  | | |      | |                                      | |
| | +----------------------------------+ | | ---> | |                                      | |
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | w2                                   | |      | | w2                                   | |
| |                                      | |      | |                                      | |
| |                                      | |      | |                                      | |
| +--------------------------------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
+------------------------------------------+      +------------------------------------------+
```

So you'd need to move it up once more to reorder at the top level and place `w1-a` above `w1-b`.

#### Moving two levels higher

If `w1-a` is physically above `w1-b` in a vertical split, and `w2` is to the right of `w1` in a horizontal split:

```
. (horizontal split)
├── w1 (vertical split)
│   ├── w1-a
│   └── w1-b
└── w2
```

then you will end up with `w1-a` being *in* the same container as the container of `w1` and `w2`.

Container tree:

```
.
├── w1-a
└── container
    ├── w1
    │   └── w1-b
    └── w2

+------------------------------------------+      +------------------------------------------+
| +-----------------+  +-----------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | w1              |  | w2              | |      | | w1-a                                 | |
| | +-------------+ |  |                 | |      | |                                      | |
| | | w1-a        | |  |                 | |      | |                                      | |
| | | (move up)   | |  |                 | |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | container (former root)              | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | +---------------+ +----------------+ | |
| | +-------------+ |  |                 | |      | | | w1            | | w2             | | |
| | +-------------+ |  |                 | | ---> | | | +-----------+ | |                | | |
| | | w1-b        | |  |                 | |      | | | | w1-b      | | |                | | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | | |           | | |                | | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | | |           | | |                | | |
| | |             | |  |                 | |      | | | +-----------+ | |                | | |
| | +-------------+ |  |                 | |      | | +---------------+ +----------------+ | |
| +-----------------+  +-----------------+ |      | +--------------------------------------+ |
+------------------------------------------+      +------------------------------------------+
```

#### Conclusion

Moving containers/windows around in i3 can be a bit unintuitive at first but if you understand which container holds which one and where they are positioned you can predict how moving a container will behave.  Bear in mind that a move operation may not always result in visible changes.

PS: Little thought experiment: If you `move left` `w1-a` in the "Reordering within the same level in the container tree" example, you get something similar to the "Moving one level higher" scenario.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I find this answer extremely confusing. AFAICS your depictions of the container trees are at least partially ignoring ordering. In the first example, if w1-a is below w1-b, why are you depicting w1-a as earlier in the tree? "Unchanged container tree (besides the position data)" ignores the ordering. Also why call a split container "w1" in one scenario, and "container" in another?

Comment: @adam-spiers Thanks for the feedbeck. I updated the post with some ascii art to hopefully make it a bit clearer

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a lot clearer! But your tree depictions are still partially ignoring ordering, and I can't see any good reason for that, so I'll fix them.

Comment: Now fixed to be crystal clear with respect to ordering and positioning.

Comment: Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 3):

My answer to this problem is having an i3helper bash script which can do this independently of layout via `focus parent` and marks. The one extracted command is:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
  moveToParent)
    i3 mark i3ha
    i3 focus parent
    i3 focus parent
    i3 mark i3hb
    i3 [con_mark="i3ha"] focus
    i3 move window to mark i3hb
    i3 unmark i3ha
    i3 unmark i3hb
    ;;
esac
```

and having it bound in i3 as:

```
# focus the parent container
bindsym $mod+a focus parent
bindsym $mod+shift+a exec i3helper moveToParent
bindsym $mod+z focus child
```

It might also be possible to bind the sequence directly, but this suits me better since I do nontrivial preprocessing of other commands too.